# How can I draw some png pictures on a TabPage in c# winforms (TabControl)?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, drawing

So I basically have 3 tabs on a winform, and what I am trying to do is, when a button is clicked in the 1st tab, to switch to the 3rd tab (System.Windows.Forms.TabControl) (which is empty) and draw some pictures on it.

What I am trying to find is a quick and easy way to display some png's on a winform.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Mechanic

EDIT1~ The way I've designed it is, there is a System.Windows.Forms.TabControl (winforms toolbox) and in the first tabPage of that exist 3 buttons which represent my main menu. What I want to do is when start (one of the buttons) is clicked, that my "map" (some .png images) will be displayed in the second tabPage.

EDIT2~ 'my map" = basically some png's that are randomly (or based on an algorithm) chosen and placed one adjacent to the other to form a square or rectangle (e.g. with 32x32 (png's by png's - the pixels of each png would prefferably be 125x125) dimensions

EDIT3~ the overall (total) size of the map should (preferably) be easily changed (not in real time, but it should be scale-able, meaning I would like (in the future) to make an "options" button that will enable the user to choose from a list of dimensions (e.g. 32x32,64x64,78x78.. any dimension really..)

Comment: Please be clearer about what you mean by __Tab__! The tabs are (usually) on top of a __Tab Control__ and used to change between the __TabPages__ in the __Tab Control__.. So, where do you want to draw the pictures??

Comment: Yes, but where do you want the pictures to appear? In the tabpages? In that case the simplest will be to place one or more pictureboxes there and load the images, a one-liner. Or as tiny images on the tabs? Look at the browser tabs with the stackoverflow logos in your browser above! How to draw there is simple too, but quite different. (Tabpages have an imageindex and work with an imagelist; also very simple..)

Comment: ok, now describe what _my "map" (some .png images) wil be displayed_ means!? One after the other or all in some layout..? Are they parts you need to combine or do they change when you click them..? SO and computers both need precise tasks..

Comment: @TaW please bare with me, because what seems to me as obvious, to another it probably isn't. (see EDIT2)

Comment: Indeed, nothing of what you now have decribed was obvious ;-)  How many pictures will make up the map? For only a few, say up 4x4 or 6x6 you may simply put pictureboxes onto the tabpage and load their Image property.  The other option is to draw them onto one bitmap. I guess I would chose one picturebox, create an emtpy bitmap as its image and draw into it..

Comment: @TaW please see EDIT3 :P, also please consider providing a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem to draw 'a few pictures' has turned out to mean: combine a flexible number of pictures into one single map.

Place one `PictureBox` of sufficient size maybe with `Dock=Fill` and `SizeMode=Center` on the target tabpage.

You will need to provide the names of the pictures if you want to load them from disk. I have chosen a List of List of string to be flexible; it is up to you to fill it correctly!!

I have hard-coded filenames I happed to have on disk. You may use code to set the filenames..

I assume that all parts of the map have the same size!

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // switch to the second tabpage:
    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;

     // i load all pictures from disk:
    string rootPath = "D:\\scrape\\sousers\\";

    // I use these hard coded pictures:
    List<List<string>> mapsParts = new List<List<string>>();
    mapsParts.Add(new List<string>()  
    { "dura.jpg", "SOU_HansP.png", "SOU_shiva.jpg", "SOU_Taw.jpg"} ) ;
    mapsParts.Add(new List<string>() 
    {"SOU_JonSkeet.jpeg", "SOU_geo.jpeg", "SOU_Antwina.jpg", "SOU_Enijar.png"} ) ;
    mapsParts.Add(new List<string>() 
    { "SOU_Ayna.jpg", "SOU_TAW2.jpg", "SOU_Lightness.jpg", "SOU_EricLippert.jpeg"} ) ;

    // i deduce the dimensions.. :
    int maxRow = mapsParts.Count;
    int maxCol = mapsParts[0].Count;

    // this is my screen dpi:
    int dpi = 96;
    // I deduce the size of one map part:
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rootPath + mapsParts[0][0]);
    int w = bmp.Width;
    int h = bmp.Height;
    bmp.Dispose();
    // now I know the total size of the map
    Bitmap bmpMap = new Bitmap(w * maxCol, h * maxRow);
    bmpMap.SetResolution(dpi, dpi); 
    // now I'll draw the parts onto the map:
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmpMap) )
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRow; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <maxCol; j++)
        {
           // read each part:
           bmp = new Bitmap(rootPath + mapsParts[i][j]);
           // make sure it has the same resolution:
           bmp.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
           // draw it
           G.DrawImage(bmp, j * w, i * h);
           // clean up
           bmp.Dispose();
        }
    // done. We can show the map:
    pictureBox1.Image = bmpMap;
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit in loading the pictures in this (kinda complicated :P) way rather than adding them to the Resources file, and then using Properties.Resources.<name> ?

Comment: Absolutely not! Absolutely do put the images into the resources __if__ you can do that!! It really doesn't matter what the source is and how you feed the drawing loop. You just need to know the x & y values where you want to put them.. Then either replace the `bmp = new Bitmap(rootPath + mapsParts[i][j]);` line with an appropriate way to set the bitmap. Or load the mapsParts from the resources..

Comment: ok, I'll try to implement all this and i'll post the code for you to review. Thanks for putting up with me :P

Comment: sure, if you have questions about my code feel free to ask. (I'll be off to bed soon, though..)